# PowerCLI- get VM cd-mount in 1 table

Tags: powershell, powercli

I try to get all the vm which have a mounted cd in one table, but the output I get is a line-by line like:

vm1
\vm1_isopath\
vm2
\vm2_isopath\

can it possible to get all the information in 1 table with 2 columns, of VM name, and ISOPath ?

my code is:

```
$VMs=Get-VM
ForEach ( $vm in $VMs)

    {
        $VMmount=Get-CDDrive -VM $vm
        if ($VMmount.IsoPath) 
        {
           $vm | select Name
           $VMmount.IsoPath

        }
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended your code to:

```js
$VMs=Get-VM

$vmInfos = @()

ForEach ( $vm in $VMs)
    {
        $VMmount=Get-CDDrive -VM $vm
        if ($VMmount.IsoPath) 
        {
            # Store needed info in hashtable
            $info = @{}
            $info.name = ($vm | select -ExpandProperty Name)
            $info.IsoPath =  $VMmount.IsoPath
            
            # Convert hashtable to custom object
            $object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $info
            
            # Add to array
            $vmInfos += $object
        }
    }

# Dump collected infos
$vmInfos | format-table -autosize
```

Hope that helps